# Extract in a row data from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hello i try to extract data from array but I need it in a row i mean every value one of a time and after loop next value.I am new to javascript and i am not very sure how to make it if someone have idea i will be happy.Thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything? please post your code.

Comment: Please show us some code of what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Did you try something if you do post then code here (if you want quick answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var data = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: thnk you for that is work of some way but is write only the last value in a array for me.I need it to write every value in numerical position 1st after this loop 2nd loop again and so on..